# Combing _Generic with other macros

Tags: c

So, I am familiar with nested macros.
Now, I want to change a macro first changed by _Generic with some other macro like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define some_func(X) _Generic((X),  \
    char* : some_func_char,         \
    default : some_func_default)(X)

#define some_func_char(X) some_func_char(X, sizeof(X)/ sizeof(char))

void (some_func_char)(char *blah, size_t len_blah)
{
  // do something
}

void some_func_default(double blah)
{
  // code
}

int main()
{
  some_func("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

but it is raising a error as

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:22: error: too few arguments to function ‘some_func_char’
    5 | #define some_func(X) _Generic((X),  \
      |                      ^~~~~~~~
main.c:22:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘some_func’
   22 |   some_func("hello");
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:10:7: note: declared here
   10 | void (some_func_char)(char *blah, size_t len_blah)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: you cant `some_func_char(domething) != some_func_char`

Comment: `sizeof some_char_pointer` is always going to be a fixed value based on the architecture (typically 4 or 8), making your macro useless (you know you're passing a `char*`, so the callee could compute the value by doing `sizeof blah` without your help); I'm guessing you think it'll get you the string length? It won't; you'd need to use `strlen`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger _sizeof some_char_pointer is always going to be a fixed value based on the architecture_. Not in this case, `sizeof` computes the size of `"Hello"` which is 6, it happens before decaying into the function.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Huh. So it decays for the purpose of `_Generic`, but isn't decayed when it's used in the macro otherwise? Interesting. Use case for `_Generic` I hadn't considered. Still going to be a problem for general usage with actual `char*`s, but I'll trust you it works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that although generic selection is not really useful except in conjunction with macros, it is not itself interpreted by the preprocessor.  Consider, then, this statement:

> ```
>   some_func("hello");
> ```

Where that appears in the example code, a definition of `some_func` as the identifier of a function-like macro is in scope, and the expansion of that macro produces this, prior to rescanning:

```
_Generic(("hello"), char *: some_func_char, default: some_func_default)("hello")
```

The preprocessor then scans that for further macro replacements, but again, `_Generic` is not a macro, and it has no other special significance to the preprocessor.  There is an in-scope definition of `some_func_char` as the identifier of a function-like macro, but the appearance of that identifier in the above line does not match it because it is not followed by an open parenthesis.  Nothing else in that line is significant (in context) to the preprocessor either, so that's in fact the final preprocessed form.

Now observe that the expression `("hello")` matches the `char *` alternative of the generic selection expression, so the function identifier `some_func_char` is the selected result, but the parenthesized argument list `("hello")` does not contain the correct number of arguments for that function.  The overall expression is a more complicated variation on trying to call `(some_func_char)("hello")`.  The `some_func_char()` macro never comes into play.

It should be clear, now, that you cannot use generic selection to select function identifiers of functions that take different numbers of arguments. But of course you *can* use it to select different function *calls*.  For example,

```
#define some_func(X) _Generic(                \
    (X),                                      \
    char *:  some_func_char((X), sizeof (X)), \
    default: some_func_default(X)             \
)

void some_func_char(char *s, size_t z) { }
void some_func_default(void *p) { }

int main(void) {
    some_func("hello");
}
```

Comment: but if I add ```int : some_func_int((X))``` in  _Generic. the compiler is showing something like ```main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:25: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘some_func_int’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    6 |     int : some_func_int((X)),                  \
      |                         ^~~
      |                         |
      |                         char *
main.c:24:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘some_func’
   24 |     some_func("hello");
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
``` Same thing for every function in _Generic. Why this is happeing?

Answer (score 2):

`some_func_char` is calling the function not the macro in the `_Generic` call (even trying to stop the expansion with the parenthesis), on the other hand, you can not ommit the second parameter in `some_func_default` if `some_func_char` expects two parameters, switch to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define some_func(X) _Generic((X),  \
    char *: some_func_char,         \
    default: some_func_default)(X, sizeof X)

void some_func_char(char *blah, size_t len_blah)
{
    // do something
}

void some_func_default(double blah, size_t dummy)
{
    (void)dummy;
    // code
}

int main()
{
    some_func("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

or better yet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define some_func(X) _Generic((X),  \
    char *: some_func_char,         \
    default: some_func_default)(X)

void some_func_char(char *blah)
{
    size_t len = strlen(blah);
    // do something
}

void some_func_default(double blah)
{
    // code
}

int main()
{
    some_func("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

This second version allows you to pass and compute the correct length also for a pointer to `char`, don't worry for the performance, `strlen` is very fast.

Also, notice that `sizeof(char)` is always 1